How do I align the X and Y axis to adjust my zoomed in grid?
I'm doing this graphing project, but I came across this problem: everytime I zoom in or out my x and y axis are out of place. Any idea of how to fix this issue?
Here my code:
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.scene.Group;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
    import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
    import javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent;
    import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class GraphingCal extends Application {

    private static final int CANVAS_WIDTH = 900;
    private static final int CANVAS_HEIGHT = 700;
    private static final double INITIAL_GRID_SIZE = 20;
    private static final double ZOOM_FACTOR = 1.1;
    private static final double MIN_GRID_SIZE = INITIAL_GRID_SIZE * 0.6;
    private static final double MAX_GRID_SIZE = INITIAL_GRID_SIZE / 0.6;

    private double gridSize = INITIAL_GRID_SIZE;
    private double xOffset = 0;
    private double yOffset = 0;
    private double prevX;
    private double prevY;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        drawGrid(gc);

        canvas.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            prevX = e.getX();
            prevY = e.getY();
        });

        canvas.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            double dx = e.getX() - prevX;
            double dy = e.getY() - prevY;
            xOffset += dx;
            yOffset += dy;
            prevX = e.getX();
            prevY = e.getY();
            drawGrid(gc);
        });

         canvas.setOnScroll((event) -> {
            double mouseX = event.getX();
            double mouseY = event.getY();

            double zoomFactor = event.getDeltaY() > 0 ? ZOOM_FACTOR : 1 / ZOOM_FACTOR;

            double newGridSize = gridSize * zoomFactor;

            if (newGridSize >= MIN_GRID_SIZE && newGridSize <= MAX_GRID_SIZE) {
                // Calculate the change in grid size
                double deltaGridSize = newGridSize - gridSize;

                xOffset -= mouseX * deltaGridSize / gridSize;
                yOffset -= mouseY * deltaGridSize / gridSize;

                gridSize = newGridSize;
            } else {
                gridSize = INITIAL_GRID_SIZE;
            }

            drawGrid(gc);
        });

        root.getChildren().add(canvas);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Graphing Calculator");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
     }

     private void drawGrid(GraphicsContext gc) {
        gc.clearRect(0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);

        // Calculate zoomed center positions
        double centerX = CANVAS_WIDTH / 3.0 + xOffset;
        double centerY = CANVAS_HEIGHT / 7.0 + yOffset;

        // Calculate the distance between each highlighted line
        double highlightedLineDistanceX = gridSize * 5;
        double highlightedLineDistanceY = gridSize * 5;

        // Draw main grid lines
        gc.setStroke(Color.LIGHTGRAY);
        for (double x = (xOffset % gridSize + CANVAS_WIDTH) % gridSize; x < CANVAS_WIDTH; x +=      gridSize) {
            gc.strokeLine(x, 0, x, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
        }
        for (double y = (yOffset % gridSize + CANVAS_HEIGHT) % gridSize; y < CANVAS_HEIGHT; y += gridSize) {
            gc.strokeLine(0, y, CANVAS_WIDTH, y);
        }

        // Draw highlighted lines aligned with x-axis scale
        gc.setStroke(Color.rgb(128, 128, 128));
        for (double x = (xOffset % highlightedLineDistanceX + CANVAS_WIDTH) % highlightedLineDistanceX; x < CANVAS_WIDTH; x += highlightedLineDistanceX) {
            gc.strokeLine(x, 0, x, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
        }

        // Draw highlighted lines aligned with y-axis scale
        for (double y = (yOffset % highlightedLineDistanceY + CANVAS_HEIGHT) % highlightedLineDistanceY; y < CANVAS_HEIGHT; y += highlightedLineDistanceY) {
            gc.strokeLine(0, y, CANVAS_WIDTH, y);
        }

        // Draw x-axis and y-axis
        gc.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        gc.strokeLine(0, centerY, CANVAS_WIDTH, centerY); // x-axis
        gc.strokeLine(centerX, 0, centerX, CANVAS_HEIGHT); // y-axis

        // Draw axis labels
        gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        gc.fillText("0", centerX + 5, centerY + 5); // Origin label
        gc.fillText("x", CANVAS_WIDTH - 10, centerY + 15); // x-axis label
        gc.fillText("y", centerX + 5, 15); // y-axis label

        // Calculate start and end scale positions based on yOffset and gridSize
        int startScaleY = (int) Math.ceil((-yOffset - CANVAS_HEIGHT / 7.0) / (highlightedLineDistanceY));
        int endScaleY = (int) Math.ceil((CANVAS_HEIGHT - yOffset - CANVAS_HEIGHT / 7.0) / (highlightedLineDistanceY));

        // Draw scale for y-axis
        for (int i = startScaleY; i <= endScaleY; i++) {
            double y = CANVAS_HEIGHT / 7.0 + highlightedLineDistanceY * i + yOffset;
            if (i != 0) {
                gc.strokeLine(centerX + 5, y, centerX - 5, y);
                gc.fillText(String.valueOf(i * -5), centerX - 30, y + 3);
            }

        }

        // Calculate start and end scale positions based on xOffset and gridSize
        int startScaleX = (int) Math.ceil((-xOffset - CANVAS_WIDTH / 3.0) / (highlightedLineDistanceX));
        int endScaleX = (int) Math.ceil((CANVAS_WIDTH - xOffset - CANVAS_WIDTH / 3.0) / (highlightedLineDistanceX));

        // Draw scale for x-axis
        for (int i = startScaleX; i <= endScaleX; i++) {
            double x = CANVAS_WIDTH / 3.0 + highlightedLineDistanceX * i + xOffset;
            if (i != 0) {
                gc.strokeLine(x, centerY - 5, x, centerY + 5);
                gc.fillText(String.valueOf(i * 5), x - 3, centerY + 20);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

I've tried to calculate their positions based on the current zoom level and offsets to adjust to the gap that happens when I zoom in and out.

Also consider [tag:jfreechart-fx], seen in this series of questions related to graphing; I can confirm that the scatter plots zoom as expected.

What are you graphing?

im trying to make something similar to desmos as my project for school

Are you referring to this desmos ?

Sample plot.  Sample plot with zoom.

yes im referring to desmos

It is a bit hard (for me) to understand the core logic you are trying to do.
So I tried to do the same thing from scratch, sticking to same principles you are following.
The key logic I am relying on is to:

calculate my drag offset always w.r.t 100% scale
calculate my center X and Y w.r.t offset and scale
calculate the first horizontal and vertical line offset from top left corner

Once I get the above factors, it is very easy to draw the canvas as you like.
Please check the below demo code for your reference. I included few conditional features just to show case how flexible it is to draw, once you have the above three factors. The convincing part is we don't draw anything outside canvas bounds ;)


import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GraphingCalModified extends Application {

    private static final int CANVAS_WIDTH = 900;
    private static final int CANVAS_HEIGHT = 700;
    private static final int INITIAL_GRID_SIZE = 20;
    private static final double MIN_GRID_SIZE = INITIAL_GRID_SIZE * 0.6;
    private static final double MAX_GRID_SIZE = INITIAL_GRID_SIZE / 0.6;
    private static final double SCALE_FACTOR = .1;
    private int gridSize = INITIAL_GRID_SIZE;
    private double prevX;
    private double prevY;

    private DoubleProperty scale = new SimpleDoubleProperty(1);
    private DoubleProperty xOffset = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    private DoubleProperty yOffset = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

    private int mouseX, mouseY;

    private boolean showMousePos, showOverflowX, showOverflowY;

    int highlightedLineDistanceX = gridSize * 5;
    int highlightedLineDistanceY = gridSize * 5;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label scaleLabel = new Label((scale.intValue() * 100) + "%");
        scaleLabel.setMouseTransparent(true);
        scaleLabel.setStyle("-fx-background-color:grey;-fx-opacity:.8;-fx-text-fill:white;-fx-background-radius:10px;-fx-padding:5px;");
        scale.addListener((obs, old, val) -> scaleLabel.setText((int) (val.doubleValue() * 100) + "%"));

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        final CheckBox showMousePosition = new CheckBox("Show Mouse Position");
        showMousePosition.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, old, val) -> {
            showMousePos = val;
        });
        showMousePosition.setSelected(true);

        final CheckBox overflowX = new CheckBox("Show Overflow X axis");
        overflowX.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, old, val) -> {
            showOverflowX = val;
            drawGrid(gc);
        });
        overflowX.setSelected(true);

        final CheckBox overflowY = new CheckBox("Show Overflow Y axis");
        overflowY.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, old, val) -> {
            showOverflowY = val;
            drawGrid(gc);
        });
        overflowY.setSelected(true);

        HBox controls = new HBox(10, scaleLabel, showMousePosition, overflowX, overflowY);
        controls.setStyle("-fx-font-size:20px;");
        controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

        StackPane canvasBox = new StackPane(canvas);
        canvasBox.setStyle("-fx-border-width:1px;-fx-border-color:lightgray;");
        VBox box = new VBox(10, controls, new Group(canvasBox));
        box.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        box.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        drawGrid(gc);

        canvas.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            prevX = e.getX();
            prevY = e.getY();
        });

        canvas.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            mouseX = (int) e.getX();
            mouseY = (int) e.getY();
            double dx = e.getX() - prevX;
            double dy = e.getY() - prevY;
            xOffset.set(xOffset.get() + (dx / scale.get()));
            yOffset.set(yOffset.get() + (dy / scale.get()));
            prevX = e.getX();
            prevY = e.getY();

            drawGrid(gc);
        });

        canvas.setOnScroll((event) -> {
            mouseX = (int) event.getX();
            mouseY = (int) event.getY();

            Point before = gridPointAtMouse();

            // Calculate the scale and the grid size
            double tempScale = event.getDeltaY() > 0 ? scale.get() + SCALE_FACTOR : scale.get() - SCALE_FACTOR;
            double newGridSize = INITIAL_GRID_SIZE * tempScale;
            if (newGridSize >= MIN_GRID_SIZE && newGridSize <= MAX_GRID_SIZE) {
                scale.set(tempScale);
                gridSize = (int) newGridSize;
            } else {
                gridSize = INITIAL_GRID_SIZE;
                scale.set(1);
            }

            // Calculate the distance between each highlighted line
            highlightedLineDistanceX = gridSize * 5;
            highlightedLineDistanceY = gridSize * 5;

            // Calculate the offset that need to be moved to ensure the mouse stays at same grid point.
            Point after = gridPointAtMouse();
            xOffset.set(xOffset.get() + (after.x - before.x) / scale.get());
            yOffset.set(yOffset.get() + (after.y - before.y) / scale.get());

            drawGrid(gc);
        });

        canvas.setOnMouseMoved(event -> {
            mouseX = (int) event.getX();
            mouseY = (int) event.getY();
            drawGrid(gc);
        });

        canvas.setOnMouseExited(event -> {
            mouseX = -1;
            mouseY = -1;
            drawGrid(gc);
        });

        primaryStage.setTitle("Graphing Calculator");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(box));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void drawGrid(GraphicsContext gc) {
        gc.clearRect(0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);

        // Calculate zoomed center position
        final Point zoomedCenter = zoomedCenter();
        int centerX = zoomedCenter.x;
        int centerY = zoomedCenter.y;

        boolean xVisible = true;
        boolean yVisible = true;

        // Calculate the first visible vertical line x offset
        int nx = Math.abs(centerX / gridSize);
        int startX;
        if (centerX < 0) {
            startX = centerX + (nx * gridSize);
            yVisible = false;
        } else {
            startX = centerX - (nx * gridSize);
            if (centerX > CANVAS_WIDTH) {
                yVisible = false;
            }
        }

        // Calculate the first visible horizontal line x offset
        int ny = Math.abs(centerY / gridSize);
        int startY;
        if (centerY < 0) {
            startY = centerY + (ny * gridSize);
            xVisible = false;
        } else {
            startY = centerY - (ny * gridSize);
            if (centerY > CANVAS_HEIGHT) {
                xVisible = false;
            }
        }

        // Draw all vertical lines
        for (int i = startX; i <= CANVAS_WIDTH; i = i + gridSize) {
            if (i == centerX) {
                // Don't draw the y axis, we will draw this on top of all lines.
                continue;
            } else if (Math.abs(i - centerX) % highlightedLineDistanceX == 0) {
                gc.setStroke(Color.rgb(128, 128, 128));
            } else {
                gc.setStroke(Color.LIGHTGRAY);
            }
            gc.strokeLine(i, 0, i, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
        }

        // Draw all horizontal lines
        for (int i = startY; i <= CANVAS_HEIGHT; i = i + gridSize) {
            if (i == centerY) {
                // Don't draw the x axis, we will draw this on top of all lines.
                continue;
            } else if (Math.abs(i - centerY) % highlightedLineDistanceY == 0) {
                gc.setStroke(Color.rgb(128, 128, 128));
            } else {
                gc.setStroke(Color.LIGHTGRAY);
            }
            gc.strokeLine(0, i, CANVAS_WIDTH, i);
        }

        // Draw x-axis and y-axis
        gc.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        if (xVisible) {
            gc.strokeLine(0, centerY, CANVAS_WIDTH, centerY); // x-axis
        }
        if (yVisible) {
            gc.strokeLine(centerX, 0, centerX, CANVAS_HEIGHT); // y-axis
        }

        // Draw labels
        gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        gc.fillText("0", centerX + 5, centerY + 15); // Origin label
        gc.fillText("x", CANVAS_WIDTH - 10, centerY + 15); // x-axis label
        gc.fillText("y", centerX + 5, 15); // y-axis label

        // Draw labels on x axis
        for (int i = startX; i <= CANVAS_WIDTH; i = i + gridSize) {
            if (Math.abs(i - centerX) % highlightedLineDistanceX == 0 && i != centerX) {
                String val = String.valueOf((i - centerX) / highlightedLineDistanceX);
                if (xVisible) {
                    // Labels on X axis
                    gc.strokeLine(i, centerY - 5, i, centerY + 5);
                    gc.fillText(val, i - 3, centerY + 20);
                } else if (showOverflowX) {
                    // Labels on top edge
                    gc.strokeLine(i, 0, i, 5);
                    gc.fillText(val, i - 3, 20);

                    // Labels on bottom edge
                    gc.strokeLine(i, CANVAS_HEIGHT - 5, i, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
                    gc.fillText(val, i - 3, CANVAS_HEIGHT - 10);
                }
            }
        }

        // Draw labels on y axis
        for (int i = startY; i <= CANVAS_HEIGHT; i = i + gridSize) {
            if (Math.abs(i - centerY) % highlightedLineDistanceY == 0 && i != centerY) {
                String val = String.valueOf((i - centerY) / highlightedLineDistanceY);
                if (yVisible) {
                    // Labels on Y axis
                    gc.strokeLine(centerX - 5, i, centerX + 5, i);
                    gc.fillText(val, centerX + 10, i);
                } else if (showOverflowY) {
                    // Labels on left edge
                    gc.strokeLine(0, i, 5, i);
                    gc.fillText(val, 10, i);

                    // Labels on right edge
                    gc.strokeLine(CANVAS_WIDTH - 5, i, CANVAS_WIDTH, i);
                    gc.fillText(val, CANVAS_WIDTH - 20, i);
                }
            }
        }

        // Draw mouse position on grid
        if (mouseX > 0 && showMousePos) {
            gc.setFill(Color.RED);
            int realX = (int) ((centerX - mouseX) / scale.get()) * -1;
            int realY = (int) ((centerY - mouseY) / scale.get()) * -1;
            gc.fillText(realX + ", " + realY, mouseX + 20, mouseY + 20);
        }
    }

    private Point zoomedCenter() {
        return new Point((int) (CANVAS_WIDTH / 3.0 + (xOffset.get() * scale.get())),
                (int) (CANVAS_HEIGHT / 7.0 + (yOffset.get() * scale.get())));
    }

    private Point gridPointAtMouse() {
        Point center = zoomedCenter();
        int realX = (int) ((center.x - mouseX) / scale.get()) * -1;
        int realY = (int) ((center.y - mouseY) / scale.get()) * -1;
        return new Point(realX, realY);
    }

    record Point(int x, int y) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

